# @Ignore'd members of certain types in RealmObject produce errors

Tags: android, realm

Consider the following code:

```
// ...
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
// ...

public class someObject extends RealmObject
{
    @PrimaryKey
    private String token;
    private byte[] data;
    private long updated;

    @Ignore
    private jsonBuilder jbRoot;

//  @Ignore
//  private JSONObject JSON; // causes compiling error once uncommented
//  @Ignore
//  private Bitmap bmp; // also causes the error
```

Prior to 0.88.0 the code above compiled perfectly. It would not compile on both 0.88.0 & 0.88.1 if I uncommented the ignored JSONObject and/or Bitmap:

```
Error:Execution failed for task     ':<package>:transformClassesWithRealmTransformerForDebug'.
> javassist.CannotCompileException: cannot find org.json.JSONObject
```

and

```
Error:Execution failed for task     ':<package>:transformClassesWithRealmTransformerForDebug'.
> javassist.CannotCompileException: cannot find android.graphics.Bitmap
```

respectively.

But it accepts the ignored private member of one of my own types as shown with the `jsonBuilder` object.

Build script in case anyone needs it:

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:0.88.1" // tried 0.88.0 as well
        }
    }
    apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

Thank you. The error above is not actually a blocker but Im just curious why that happens. But I like the 0.88.x changes. :)

**UPDATE**: should be fixed soon (see comments)

**UPDATE2**: fixed in the snapshot build (see comments)

Comment: This actually looks like a bug we should look into. Would you mind opening an issue here? https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues

Comment: @Emanuelez: sure. Will do so once I reach my PC.

Comment: I think this one should be fixed by https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/2424 and has been released in 0.88.1.

Comment: @beeender As I said in the post I have also tried the 0.88.1 version.

Comment: @atomontage Sorry, i missed that. I can confirm this error and i just created a issue in our repo https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2478 . We will fix it very soon.

Comment: @beeender No problem. Thank you both for quick replies!

Comment: Fixed by https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/2483 . The snapshot release would be available in couple of hours.